# how to take screenshot by vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

i need know how to take screenshot by vbscript
i see this function

```
Function CaptureScreenShot(ScreenshotPath )  
  'Generate Name of the Image 
  strimgFileName="Img\Img" & Day(Date)& Month(Date) & Year(Date) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now) &".jpg"  
  strImgFile= ScreenshotPath & strimgFileName   
  'Capture failure Screen shot 
  Set objPic = Sys.Desktop.Picture()  
  'Save captured Screen shot 
  ExecutionStatus = objPic.SaveToFile(strImgFile)  
  'Return Captured image name
  CaptureScreenShot=".\" & strimgFileName  
End Function
```

but it's not work! idk why can anyone give me a good codes
to take screen shot and save it in temp dircetory
thx all

Comment: That code isn't vbscript. From Help `You cannot send the PRINT SCREEN key {PRTSC} to an application.
`

Comment: You can take a look at this vbscript ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549077/auto-screenshot-using-vbs?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35549077/50447

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Screenshot using VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549077/auto-screenshot-using-vbs)